# ReactWebChat EndofConversation type

Tags: reactjs, botframework, web-chat

How to know if the chat is ended in **ReactWebChat Directline API**? Right now I didn't see any types indicating that the chat has been ended. I'm using the npm package **"botframework-webchat": "^4.9.0"**.

Right now this is the only thing you will see at the end of the chat.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can send an activity of your choice back to the bot if you utilize `window.onbeforeunload`, Web Chat's `store`, and an event listener, as shown below. Works perfectly for me. This [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event) shows how you can setup the `store`.

```js
window.addEventListener( 'sendEventActivity', ( { data } ) => {
  store.dispatch( {
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
    payload: {
      text: data
    }
  } )
} );

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  const eventSendActivity = new Event( 'sendEventActivity' );
  eventSendActivity.data = 'User left conversation';
  window.dispatchEvent( eventSendActivity );
}
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Right now it only fires when you reload the page. But I will dive deep into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldn't make it work. The problem I have is when I finished the conversation there is no indicator that it has finished. So when I reload it or navigate to other and back. You can still type to the sendBox and repeat the conversation again.